# Opening HTM worksheet in current (opened) workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro program to copy values from HTM page. (Kind of data back up).
Is there a chance to open the HTM page in current workbook, that I run macro from?
Now it works like: Different workbook is opened - I pull the needed data - I am closing the workbook.

I attach my code below...

```
Sub Button23_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim DlPath, HypLink As String
Dim imgname, IP As String

DlPath = "H:\OP-ShapeCzech\0501-Mfg\Staff-Public\Welding Technician\ROBOTI\Záloha FANUC\Autobackup\Test\W30\"
IP = "10.110.13.172"


Workbook.Open Filename:="http://" & IP & "/MD/INDEX_TP.HTM"

Set ws = Sheets("INDEX_TP")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 13 To LastRow
   imgname = Cells(i, 1).Value
   HypLink = "http://" & IP & "/MD/" & imgname
   URLDownloadToFile 0, HypLink, DlPath & imgname & ".", 0, 0
Next i
 
ActiveSheet.Close

MsgBox "TP programs and Variable files have been saved !!!", vbInformation

Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & ("H:\OP-ShapeCzech\0501-Mfg\Staff-Public\Welding Technician\ROBOTI\Záloha FANUC\Autobackup\Test\W30\"), vbNormalFocus 'Otevreni zalozene slozky                 

End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbook.Open` is not intended to open htm files (it is intended to open workbooks). I recommend to search for "web scraping with VBA" there are tons of tutorials how to get values from websites properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to **scrape** your page with MSHTML library.
Here you can find a simple example, how to load a file from URL:

```
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With html.createDocumentFromUrl("http://url/path/of/your/file.htm", "")
    
        Debug.Print .body.innerHTML

    End With
```

As HTML shall be valid XML you can use the MSXML2 library to parse this file.
You can find quite well documentation for this library on MS pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms764730(v=vs.85)